# The public type inherit must be defined in its own file

Tags: java

```
class Suuper
{

    int value=100;

    public void fnsuper()
    {
        System.out.println("This is super class");

    }
}   
class sub1 extends Suuper
{

    public void fnsub1()
    {
        System.out.println("Superclass values is:"+ value);
        System.out.println("Sub class one");
    }


}
class sub2 extends Suuper
{
    void fnsub2()
    {
        System.out.println("Superclass value is:" + value);
        System.out.println("Sub class two");
    }
}
public class inherit
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        sub1 obj1 = new sub1();
        obj1.fnsub1();
        obj1.fnsuper();

        sub2 obj2 = new sub2();
        obj2.fnsub2();
        obj2.fnsuper();


    }

}
```

I am just trying Inheritance concept in the above program, please solve my questions.

1. When I add public in the "class inherit" i am getting the error as "The public type inherit must be defined in its own file".
2. Also when I run the program without public in class name(class inherit). I am getting the output as "javarstanding".

I am a beginner in java, please me out to solve this program and please explain what mistake i have done in this program.

Comment: Well, move the `inherit` class to its own `inherit.java` file, what's the problem?

Comment: It's telling you exactly what to do to fix it. Also, classes normally begin with a capital letter in Java.

Comment: _" please explain what mistake i have done in this program."_ What could be more clear than _"The public type inherit must be defined in its own file"_ ?

Comment: I have moved Inherit.java as separate java file. Now I can able to run the program. Thanks a lot lexicore

Answer (score 0):

`public` classes in Java, have to be defined in their own file, whereas the filename is the same as the class name.

When you define a `public class inherit`, that class has to be in a file called `inherit.java`.

Additionally, the file has to be inside the directory, that your `package` statement suggests. Since you don't have one in your example, you can just put the file in your source root directory.

Comment: Thank you Link 64, Mr.David Conrad, Mr.Fildor. I'll follow these inputs in rest of my java training